# Custom BeanUtils Converter not called

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to write my own bean utils converter so that I can export my object to a plain text file

I have the main class

```
 public class BeanUtilsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.setId(3l);
        myObject.setName("My Name");

        ConvertUtilsBean cub = new ConvertUtilsBean();
        cub.deregister(String.class);
        cub.register(new MyStringConverter(), String.class);
        cub.deregister(Long.class);
        cub.register(new MyLongConverter(), Long.class);

        System.out.println(cub.lookup(String.class));
        System.out.println(cub.lookup(Long.class));

        BeanUtilsBean bub = new BeanUtilsBean(cub, new PropertyUtilsBean());

        String name = bub.getProperty(myObject, "name");
        System.out.println(name);
        String id = bub.getProperty(myObject, "id");
        System.out.println(id);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Long Converter

```
public class MyLongConverter implements Converter{

    @Override
    public Object convert(Class clazz, Object value) {
        System.out.println("Long convert");
        return value.toString()+"l";
    }

}
```

The String Converter

```
public class MyStringConverter implements Converter{

    @Override
    public Object convert(Class clazz, Object value) {
        System.out.println("String convert");
        return value.toString()+":";
    }
}
```

Finally my object

```
public class MyObject {
    Long id; 
    String name;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The Output

```
String convert
My Name:
String convert
3:
```

I was expecting the id will go through MyLongConverter, but it seems it is still going thru the String one. Why and how can I fix this?

Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String id = bub.getProperty(myObject, "id");
```

Above `getProperty` function in `BeanUtilBean` class has to return `String` representation of the property you requested, regardless of what format the property is defined. So, it will always use `String` converter (`MyStringConverter`).

Since the destination type here is always `String`, `MyLongConverter` will never be used.

Instead, `MyStringConverter` should inspect the type of the value parameter and accordingly convert  it to `String`.

Comment: This is correct. I have to do a lot of if/else if case to convert each type to string. I thought the converter converts which ever ("from")type when I register. but it is actually converting "to"